# date time sorting with nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a condition where I'm stuck right now, so basically I want to sort my array with the values of its nested array. I want to sort the parent array called `arr` with the date-time of its nested array called `notifications`. I want only those objects should come first which has updated `createdAt` of `notifications`.

```
const arr = [ 
    {
        "name": "Two"
        "notifications": [
            {
                "name": "Notification of two (1)",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-17T10:30:03.629262Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Notification of two (1)",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-17T10:30:03.629262Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "One"
        "notifications": [
            {
                "name": "Notification of one (1)",
                "createdAt": "2022-03-17T10:30:03.629262Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "Notification of one (1)",
                "createdAt": "2022-03-17T10:30:03.629262Z"
            }
        ]
    }    
]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you simply want to sort the elements within the embedded `notifications` arrays? Or do you want to sort the elements in `arr`? If the latter, which of the multiple dates within each `arr` item's `notifications` would you sort on?

Comment: I want to sort `arr` on behalf of notifications `createdAt`

Comment: That doesn't clarify the requirement, for me at least. Each item in `arr` potentially has multiple notifications with createdAt.

Comment: @jarmod I want to sort the elements of `arr`. I simply want those elements on the top of the list which `notifications.createdAt`  has an updated date.

Comment: @jarmod if you see in the above list that `"name": "One" ` is on the second index but I want it at the first index because if has updated `notifications`

Comment: I mean nearest `createdAt`  of today's date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to solve the problem. It calculates the maximum date for each item's notification and then performs a descending sort on that maximum date.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "Two",
    notifications: [
      {
        name: "Notification of two (1)",
        createdAt: "2021-03-17T10:30:03.629262Z",
      },
      {
        name: "Notification of two (1)",
        createdAt: "2021-03-17T10:30:03.629262Z",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "One",
    notifications: [
      {
        name: "Notification of one (1)",
        createdAt: "2022-03-17T10:30:03.629262Z",
      },
      {
        name: "Notification of one (1)",
        createdAt: "2022-03-17T10:30:03.629262Z",
      },
    ],
  },

];

const max_date = (x) =>
  Math.max.apply(
    null,
    x.notifications.map((n) => new Date(n.createdAt))
  );

// Descending sort by maximum date
arr.sort((x, y) => max_date(y) - max_date(x));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer to follow-up question: if instead of `createdAt` being a timestamp, let's say you had a simple boolean called `notified` and you wanted to sort notified items before non-notified items.

In the example below we simply count the number of `notified=true` properties and sort descending on that. So, all items with 1+ `notified=true` come before items with 0 `notified=true` and an item with 2x `notified=true` comes before an item with 1x `notified=true`.

```
const notif_count = (x) => x.notifications.filter((n) => n.notified).length;

// Descending sort by count of notified=true
arr.sort((x, y) => notif_count(y) - notif_count(x));
```

Comment: It works according to my requirements! thanks, I've another use case what if instead of the date field I have a boolean field? same data but support `createdAt` field is boolean

Comment: You would need a different comparison function when calling sort. If you wanted items with one or more 'true' notifications to appear before items with all 'false' notifications then use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test if some of the notification values are 'true'. The [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) callback function would then need to return <0, 0, or >0, as appropriate.

Comment: Added an example that, instead of using `some`, counts the number of boolean trues (so the more trues the higher your sort order).